# 2.8 sharp color over seam color

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edges

Is it possible to change sharp edges beeing displayed over seams, like in the 2.79? Right now in 2.8 seams are on the top of the sharps.

[image: Cube with seams color over sharp color]